# Save XML into list or array?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, c#-4.0

We have a 600K-line XML file with tons of data. Of all the data, what I need to read are the nodes `<mv>`, and the way to know which `<mv>` I want to read is because it has an element `<mod>` inside with text that begins with *"ValueAssigned=1, Function=1, Id="*

This is not a complete XML string by any means, but this would be *some sort* of example.

The end result would be to match each `Id` with its values in `<t>`.

```
<mv>
<mod>ValueAssigned=1, Function=1, Id=1</mod>
<t>123</t>
<t>20</t>
<t>10</t>
<t>40</t>
</mv>
<mv>
<mod>ValueAssigned=1, Function=1, Id=2</mod>
<t>300</t>
<t>21</t>
<t>56</t>
<t>30</t>
</mv>
```

The result would be to save this into a table. I don't need help saving the data into the table, but I do need help trying to save all those sections into some type of list:

```
ID  Value
1   123
1   20
1   10
1   40
2   300
2   21
2   56
2   30
```

I was thinking of something like this, but I haven't tried it yet:

```
string textToFind = "ValueAssigned=1, Function=1, Id=";
IEnumerable<XElement> query1 = doc.Descendants("mod").Where(c => c.Value == TextToFind).Ancestors("mv");
```

Thanks.

Comment: @WinterMute The designer of that xml file needs to learn about xml

Comment: *I was thinking of something like this, but I haven't tried it yet*.  So give it a try, and if it doesn't work, we can help.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert your xml to `Dictionary<string,List<int>>`

```
Dictionary<string,List<int>> dict = 
                XDocument.Load(filename)
                .Descendants("mv")
                .ToDictionary(x => Regex.Match((string)x.Element("mod"), @"Id=(\d+)")
                                        .Groups[1].Value,
                              x=>x.Elements("t").Select(t=>(int)t).ToList());
```

Complete working code:

```
string xml = @"
<root>
    <mv>
        <mod>ValueAssigned=1, Function=1, Id=1</mod>
        <t>123</t>
        <t>20</t>
        <t>10</t>
        <t>40</t>
    </mv>
    <mv>
        <mod>ValueAssigned=1, Function=1, Id=2</mod>
        <t>300</t>
        <t>21</t>
        <t>56</t>
        <t>30</t>
    </mv>
</root>
";

Dictionary<string,List<int>> dict = 
                XDocument.Parse(xml)
                .Descendants("mv")
                .ToDictionary(x => Regex.Match((string)x.Element("mod"), @"Id=(\d+)").Groups[1].Value,
                              x=>x.Elements("t").Select(t=>(int)t).ToList());

foreach(var kv in dict)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ID: {0}  Ts: {1}", kv.Key, string.Join(",", kv.Value));
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it.  You may want to add `.Where(x => x.Element("mod") != null && x.Element("mod").Value.StartsWith("ValueAssigned=1, Function=1"))` after `.Descendants("mv")`.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I get "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.". Apparently, this isn't a well-formed XML file and I can't open it correctly in a browser of XML editor.